# Angular projects in Visual Studio

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

As we know the Angular (2+) applications are pure JavaScript applications...

Why there is a need to create an ASP.NET (Core?) project in "MS Visual Studio" in order to build an Angular application?

How and why the Microsoft .NET is linked with the Google Angular, and is there a workaround to build a pure Angular 2 application using Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: Why use ms visual studio?

Comment: Because I host the project in VSTS.

Comment: Using VSTS does not force you to use ms visual studio. You can create a git repo and use command line as you would if you used gitlab.

Comment: I don't see how your comment is linked with the questions from the OP, I want to use Visual Studio and build an Angular project, is that possible?

Comment: My opinion is that you should not be bound to an IDE, but adapt. I think ms visual studio creates a core app in order to have all the IDE's tools like start debug publish etc. So probably if you manage to set up an app without those, then you obviously don't need visual studio. I am not you downvoter, relax.

Comment: I have to build however a .NET Web API to serve the Angular Client, so I would prefer to use a only one solution to host both projects... and not have to build and deploy twice...

Comment: Deploy your API in a local iis(not express) and you won't have to build.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2017, there is an option to open a folder. There are no solution or project files when opening a project like this, but there will be a .vs folder. You can use Team Explorer to connect to your VSTS repository.

Run the app through the Angular CLI using the command `ng serve` in the command line. You will want to get familiar with the [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/), if you aren't already.